# Using VS Code debugger for serverless lambda flask applications

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, aws-lambda, wsgi, aws-serverless

I have been creating some Lambda functions on AWS using the serverless framework, Flask and SLS WSGI. Some dynamodb tables but that should not matter in this case.

The problem that I am facing is that I can not debug the whole thing end to end, I am able to run `sls wsgi serve` and run a local instance of my lambda functions, happy days. However, I am a little bit spoiled by other dev tools, languages and IDEs (even just Flask itself) that allow me to set breakpoints and see the scope, step through etc. So I would really like to be able to get that done here as well.

I tried launching the sls command mentioned above in a launch configuration inside vs code, no luck. Next thing I tried was to run the default flask launch config but that obviously didn't include all the configuration stored in the sls.yml file which is essential for accessing the local dynamodb instance.

The last thing I tried was to attach to ptvsd at the end of my app.py file. So I would hit a `wait` action from ptvsd, attach the debugger in vs code to the specified port, which seems to be successful and returning the code execution. However, it seems like sls wsgi runs the file twice, so that the attaching happens for the first instance and not the second, which then does not trigger a breakpoint when I try to execute an API call through Postman.

I guess I could include the `wait` step everywhere manually, then attach for each method that I am trying to debug inside the code instead of in the IDE, but that seems like overkill and not very convenient.

I have been looking for answers online and reading through docs and could find no further.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that I can use `Attach using Process Id` It is however a little bit tricky because there are always 2 processes running in the list (different pid's). Its not great, but it does the trick

Answer (score 0):

One technique I have found useful, albeit in a node environment but should apply here, is to make use of unit testing as a way to execute code locally with the ability to tie in a debuggerm as well as make use of mocking to stub away the external dependencies such as AWS services (S3, DynamoDB, etc). I wrote a blog post about setting this up for node but you may find it useful as a way to consider setting things up with Pythoin as well: https://serverless.com/blog/serverless-local-development/

However, in the world of serverless development, it ultimately doesn't matter how sophisticated you get with your local development environment, you will **have to** to test in the cloud environment as well. The unit testing technique I described is good for catching those basic syntactical and logical errors but you still will need to perform a deployment into the cloud and test in that environment. Its one of the reasons at Serverless we are working very hard on ways to improve the ability and time it takes to deploy to the cloud so that testing in AWS is replaces local testing.